# Logic Apps - looping through a nested array in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, azure-logic-apps

I need to loop through this optional array (it's only the sectional of JSON I have trouble with).

As you can see from the code:

The optional **bullseye** has an array **rings**. rings has arrays of **expansionCriteria** and expansionCriteria may or may not have **actions**.

How do I iterate and get all **type**, **threshold** in expansionCriteria? I also need to access all **skillsToRemove** under **actions**, if available.

I am rather new to Logic Apps, so any help is appreciated.

```
        "bullseye": {
        "rings": [
          {
            "expansionCriteria": [
              {
                "type": "TIMEOUT_SECONDS",
                "threshold": 180
              }
            ],
            "actions": {
              "skillsToRemove": [
                {
                  "name": "Claims Foundation",
                  "id": "60bd469a-ebab-4958-9ca9-3559636dd67d",
                  "selfUri": "/api/v2/routing/skills/60bd469a-ebab-4958-9ca9-3559636dd67d"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Claims Advanced",
                  "id": "bdc0d667-8389-4d1d-96e2-341e383476fc",
                  "selfUri": "/api/v2/routing/skills/bdc0d667-8389-4d1d-96e2-341e383476fc"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Claims Intermediate",
                  "id": "c790eac3-d894-4c00-b2d5-90cd8a69436c",
                  "selfUri": "/api/v2/routing/skills/c790eac3-d894-4c00-b2d5-90cd8a69436c"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "expansionCriteria": [
              {
                "type": "TIMEOUT_SECONDS",
                "threshold": 5
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
    }
```

Please let me know if you need more info.

To generate the schema, you can remove the name of the object at the top of the code: **"bullseye":**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [pramodvalavala-msft](https://learn.microsoft.com/answers/users/111253/pramodvalavala-msft.html)  for posting your answer in [MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/104751/azure-logic-apps-loop-through-json-object.html) for the similar thread .

" As you are working with a JSON Object instead of an Array, unfortunately there is no built-in function to loop over the keys. There is a  [feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/39685522-function-to-retrieve-keys-from-json-object)  to add a method to extract keys from an object for scenarios like this, that you could up vote for it gain more traction.

You can use the  [inline code action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code)  to extract the keys from your object as an array (using  [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)). And then you can loop over this array using the  [foreach loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-loops#foreach-loop)  to extract the object that you need from the main object, which you could then use to create records in dynamics."

For more information you can refer the below links:

. [How to loop and extract items from Nested Json Array in Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60553425/how-to-loop-and-extract-items-from-nested-json-array-in-logic-apps) .

.[Nested ForEach Loop in Workflow.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8b407f69-808b-49a5-95cf-3ea1be2cac1d/nested-foreach-loop-in-workflow?forum=azurelogicapps) .

Comment: Thank you. We have now resolved the issues and I noticed your reply. Yes, we flatten the values - one level at a time and then process them in a for each loop.